# Как определить на какую кнопку нажал пользователь

Tags: android, c#, button, xamarin, click

Итак, есть 5 кнопок на экране, нужно определить на какую кнопку нажал пользователь и взять её тег после чего редирект на другое активити. Пытался сделать это так:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetTheme(Android.Resource.Style.ThemeDeviceDefaultLightNoActionBar);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainScreen);

    Button BtnHm = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Home);
    BtnHm.Click += SwitchActivity;

    Button BtnSrch = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Search);
    BtnSrch.Click += SwitchActivity;

    Button BtnLstOfPh = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.ListOfPhotos);
    BtnLstOfPh.Click += SwitchActivity;

    Button BtnGlr = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Glory);
    BtnGlr.Click += SwitchActivity;

    Button BtnMyAcc = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.MyAcc);
    BtnMyAcc.Click += SwitchActivity;
}

public void SwitchActivity(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button sendBtn = (Button)sender;

    switch (sendBtn.Tag)
    {
        case 1:
            Intent toMain = new Intent(this, typeof(MainScreenActivity));
            StartActivity(toMain);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent toSearch = new Intent(this, typeof(SearchActivity));
            StartActivity(toSearch);
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent toPhoto = new Intent(this, typeof(ListOfPhotoActivity));
            StartActivity(toPhoto);
            break;
        case 4:
            Intent toGlory = new Intent(this, typeof(GloryActivity));
            StartActivity(toGlory);
            break;
        case 5:
            Intent toUser = new Intent(this, typeof(UserActivity));
            StartActivity(toUser);
            break;
    }
}
```

Но мне подчеркивает в `case` цифры и пишет что требуется постоянное значение. Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой тип у ```sendBtn.Tag``` ?

Comment: @tym32167 прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, но как посмотреть?Юзаю VS2017

Comment: Навести мышкой на него и его тип выскочит подсказкой

Comment: @tym32167 добавил в вопрос

Comment: То есть, в соответствии со скрином, вы пытаетесь сравнить 2 разных типа - Java.Lang.Object и int. Потому у вас и не компилирутеся.

Comment: @tym32167 но так не должно быть, поскольку в `axml`  к этому активити написано`android:tag="@integer/btn1"`, а уже в файле `integer.xml` написано `<integer name="btn1">1</integer>`

Comment: android? а какая это платформа? Xamarin?

Comment: @VladD VisualStudioXamarin

Comment: *offtopic: с точки зрения джавера код режет глаза, аж жесть, ну просто спасу нет. Претензии к ТС нет, просто непривычно :) *

Comment: @Barmaley: А чем режет глаза? PascalCasing и нет египетских скобок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вы ни писали в xml, в свойство Tag любое значение будет паковаться (Tag - всё же object). При запросе свойства вы будете всегда получать object, поэтому нужно провести распаковку:

```
switch ((int) sendBtn.Tag)
```

Answer (score 3):

Тебе нужно присвоить каждой кнопке Id и в конструкции switch() искать view-элемент по id
пример:

```
     switch(sendBtn.getId()){
case R.id.btn1:
...
case R.id.btn2:
...}
```

Если это не подходит для Вашего языка программирования, я надеюсь, что мой ответ подскажет вам путь решения данной проблемы. Всего хорошего)

Comment: Выбивает ошибку о том что Button не содержит определения для getId

Comment: @МаксимБуяков вам нужно свойство `sendBtn.Id` и switch по нему.

Answer (score 1):

XAML

```
`<Button x:Name="But_01" BindingContext="01" Clicked="Button_Click />" 
 <Button x:Name="But_02" BindingContext="02" Clicked="Button_Click />"`
```

XAML.CS

```
`private void Button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    String name_button = Convert.ToString(btn.BindingContext);
    switch (name_button)
    {
        case "01":
            //Нажата кнопка 01
            break;
        case "02":
            //Нажата кнопка 02
            break;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем все эти кэйсы? Можно же создать для каждой кнопки отдельный ивент. Вот так:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

  SetTheme(Android.Resource.Style.ThemeDeviceDefaultLightNoActionBar);
  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainScreen);

  Button BtnHm = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Home);
  BtnHm.Click += SwitchActivityByHm;

  Button BtnSrch = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Search);
  BtnSrch.Click += SwitchActivityBySrch;

  Button BtnLstOfPh = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.ListOfPhotos);
  BtnLstOfPh.Click += SwitchActivityByLstOfPh;

  Button BtnGlr = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Glory);
  BtnGlr.Click += SwitchActivityByGlr;

  Button BtnMyAcc = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.MyAcc);
  BtnMyAcc.Click += SwitchActivityByMyAcc;
}

public void SwitchActivityByHm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Intent toMain = new Intent(this, typeof(MainScreenActivity));
  StartActivity(toMain);
}

public void SwitchActivityBySrch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Intent toSearch = new Intent(this, typeof(SearchActivity));
  StartActivity(toSearch);
}

public void SwitchActivityByLstOfPh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Intent toPhoto = new Intent(this, typeof(ListOfPhotoActivity));
  StartActivity(toPhoto);
}

public void SwitchActivityByGlr(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Intent toGlory = new Intent(this, typeof(GloryActivity));
  StartActivity(toGlory);
}

public void SwitchActivityByMyAcc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Intent toUser = new Intent(this, typeof(UserActivity));
  StartActivity(toUser);
}
```